# Notifications for changes in user data in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I created a subscription in Azure AD for receiving notification when a user is deleted. But I'm not receiving any notifications when I delete or update a user. I got 201 code, so every thing is ok. I've been waiting for more than 24 hours !

```js
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity",
    "id": "5bfc6bc2-a4bd-4e03-b420-7f5f72158dab",
    "resource": "users",
    "applicationId": "4547857b-a6ce-424f-8f71-d1f0c8050c59",
    "changeType": "updated,deleted",
    "clientState": null,
    "notificationUrl": "https://8ffa2519154d.ngrok.io/azure/notifications",
    "expirationDateTime": "2020-09-16T11:05:00Z",
    "creatorId": "78f2eabd-f0a5-4350-b541-ef9edb47ae80",
    "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}
```

Comment: Could you please tey to debugg your webhhok to check if you have receive message?

Comment: @JimXu how can I do it ?

Comment: you can add code to add a record into azure sql when you receive notifications

Comment: @JimXu to receive notifications on the notificationUrl, do i have to create a webhook? and in which runbook ? sory, but I am a beginner in azure  !

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand.

Comment: In other words, what do I have to do after creating a subscription ?

Comment: Could you please tell me how you create notification webhook?

Comment: I created a subscription, via https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions, and got result as shown above. I didn't create notification webhook. How can I do it please ?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set up notifications for changes in user data, please refer to the following steps.

1. Create a webhook. I sue Azure function node httptrigger as webhook

a. define `INotification.ts` to receive notification data

```
export interface INotificationResourceData {
  id: string;
  "@odata.type": string;
  "@odata.id": string;
  "@odata.etag": string;
}

export interface INotification {
  subscriptionId: string;
  subscriptionExpirationDateTime: string;
  tenantId: string;
  changeType: string;
  clientState: string;
  resource: string;
  resourceData: INotificationResourceData;
}

export interface INotificationsPayload {
  value: INotification[];
}
```

b. function code

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import { INotificationsPayload } from "../entities/INotification";

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest
): Promise<void> {
  context.log("HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
  // Validate the subscription creation
  if (req.query.validationToken) {
    context.log("Validating new subscription...");
    context.log("Validation token:");
    context.log(req.query.validationToken);
    context.res = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
      },
      body: req.query.validationToken,
    };
  } else {
    context.log("Received new notification from Microsoft Graph...");
    context.log("Notifications: ");
    const payload = req.body as INotificationsPayload;
    payload.value.forEach((n, i) => {
      const resourceData = JSON.stringify(n.resourceData);
      context.log(` Notification #${i} `);
      context.log(`----------------------------------------------------------`);
      context.log(`Subscription Id    : ${n.subscriptionId}`);
      context.log(`Expiration         : ${n.subscriptionExpirationDateTime}`);
      context.log(`Change Type        : ${n.changeType}`);
      context.log(`Client State       : ${n.clientState}`);
      context.log(`Resource           : ${n.resource}`);
      context.log(`Resource Data      : ${resourceData}`);
      context.log(`----------------------------------------------------------`);
    });
    context.res = { body: "" };
  }
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

2. Create a subscription. For example create subscrpition fro user resource

```
Post  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions

Body:
{
   "changeType": "updated,deleted",
   "notificationUrl": "https://2f148f1102ab.ngrok.io/api/Webhook",
   "resource": "/users",
   "expirationDateTime":"2020-09-17T10:27:03.4541718Z",
   "clientState": "secretClientValue",
   "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}
```

when we create a subscription, it will validate the notification endpoint via sending a post request to our webhook.
[image]
Response:
[image]

3. Test

Update user with Microsoft graph

```
Patch https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/2632566d-711d-4f07-a595-afd426361b2c
Body
{
  
  "country":"US"
}
```

After successfully updating, I receive the notification as below
[image]

For further details about it, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#managing-subscriptions) and [here](https://ypcode.wordpress.com/2020/01/13/explore-microsoft-graph-subscriptions-part-ii-azure-functiond-like-a-pro/)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, but something went wrong. I have followed all the steps, and I created a subscription with azure function url as notificationUrl, and got the first notification "Validation token: ..", but when I update a user I got nothing !

Comment: @MehdiJomaa Is that your azure function has no output?

Comment: yes, when I create a subscription I get output, but when I update user I get nothing

Comment: @MehdiJomaa have you seen the action in the Azure AD log? Besides, Have you done that in the right tenant?

Comment: yes, I can see the action when I click "Audit Log" from the menu of Monitoring. What do you mean by "in the right tenant" please ?

Comment: When deleting a user, Microsoft Graph only sends an 'updated' notification when a successful subscription has "changeType": "updated,deleted"

Comment: @ScottHillson It is a known issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#additional-notifications-for-users.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine pointed out today that the "delete" change notification is not triggered until users go in and "Permanently delete" the deleted users. [image]